# Add percentage sign (%) in a column header generated with KableExtra in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to have the percentage sign in a column header in an Rmarkdown file that will be knitted to PDF

````
---
output: pdf_document
---


```{r}
library(kableExtra, messages = FALSE )
knitr::kable(data.frame(Score = c(10, 34), Percent(%) = c(1.5, 6)),
         escape = FALSE)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, there are reasons you will not want to name the column of the data.frame in such a way. Here is an alternative for your knitr chunk -- specify the column names separately using the `col.names` argument in the `knitr::kable` function.

```
library(kableExtra)
df <- data.frame(Score = c(10, 34), Percent = c(1.5, 6))
knitr::kable(df, 
             col.names = c("Score", "Percent (%)"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey in theory you can try:

```
data.frame("Score" = c(10, 34), "Percent(%)" = c(1.5, 6),check.names=FALSE)
```

For display it's fine, but you might run into some pesky problems downstream if you try to use this column..